# How can I pass a 3 dimensional tensor into a dense layer (tensorflow.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow.js

I'm looking for a way to feed in a normalized graph into my tensorflow.js model. Right now, it is passing in a 2-dimensional tensor and that code works flawlessly. I found a new data point that I want to add into that 2-dimensional tensor, however, that data point is an array of points that when normalized, it ranges between 0-1. If there was a set number of points the array had, I would just each individual one as a data point; however, the size of the array varies between all my data. Here is my code and an example data set in javascript object form:

```json
{
    "rank": "27",
    "fame": "4505",
    "deaths": "1",
    "accountAge": 199,
    "characters": "7",
    "skins": "0",
    "verified": 1,
    "oneDay": [ 3856, 4003, 4138, 4282, 4316, 4431, 4505, 4719],
    "oneWeek": [ 1100, 1243, 1511, 1948, 2814, 3267, 3557],
    "lifeTime": [231, 1711, 2257, 4104, 5366, 7610, 9142, 11123, 12831, 15003, 15154, 16600, 17438, 18466, 19777, 20626, 22230, 24180, 24970, 25918, 26728, 28325, 29318, 30187, 30645, 31068, 33142, 35088, 35582, 35984, 37162, 39567, 0, 41089, 42615, 43609, 44254, 46740, 47231, 48261, 50673, 51161, 52646, 53592, 55470, 56487, 57254, 58422, 58428, 62407, 65122, 0, 65122, 69784, 70703, 72511, 77764, 78240, 80642, 81143, 81204, 82929, 85771, 89594, 90746, 92073, 92265, 376, 425, 476, 702, 776, 777, 827, 828, 1089, 1091, 998, 1031, 1084, 1148, 1100    ]
}
```

The model setup

```js
    model = tf.sequential();

    //input layer
    model.add(tf.layers.dense({
        units: 100,
        inputShape: [9],
        activation: 'sigmoid'
    }))

    //hidden layers
    model.add(tf.layers.dense({
        units: 50,
        activation: 'sigmoid'
    }))

    //output layer
    model.add(tf.layers.dense({
        units: 1,
        activation: 'sigmoid'
    }))
```

The current data setup

```js
var xs2D = [], ys2D = []
for (let i of data) {
    //removed data normalization because it was very big

    xs2D.push([rank, fame, deaths, age, char, skin, od, ow, lt])
    ys2D.push([i.verified])
}

const xs = tf.tensor2d(xs2D)
const ys = tf.tensor2d(ys2D)
```

Comment: Do you mean xs is a 3d tensor ?

Answer (score 0):

If `xs` is a 3d tensor of shape `[a, b, c]`, then inputShape of the first layer should be `[b, c]`.

Since `ys` is not a 3d tensor, then a flatten later should be pass before the last layer, for it to return a 2d tensor.

Here is a small example:

```
const model = tf.sequential({
     layers: [tf.layers.dense({units: 1, inputShape: [1, 10]}),
              tf.layers.flatten(),
              tf.layers.dense({units: 1})]
});
model.compile({optimizer: 'sgd', loss: 'meanSquaredError'}); 
// the loss function and the optimizer are just for the sake of example 
// in order to use compile, required before using fit

await model.fit(tf.ones([8, 1, 10]), tf.ones([8, 1]));
model.predict(tf.ones([8, 1, 10]))
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. That makes a lot of sense. I started implementing that, and now I'm getting an error saying `Shape does not match typed-array in bindData()`
I changed the data setup to this:
`[[[rank], [fame], [deaths], [age], [char], [skin], od, ow, lt]]`

Comment: Is the 3d tensor well created ? You cannot create tensor in tfjs with non-uniform shapes. They are called ragged tensors. They are not yet available if tfjs and can't be used for training models. `[rank]` does not have the same length as `lt`

Comment: Oh dang they aren't all the same size :^(

Comment: So sorry to say, you can't do what you want. But maybe you can flatten all the data to a single array